# Update value in same view using CASE expression

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I am creating a view where i have daily data of different items and each item has a state. I created a column that shows what the column was yesterday using

```
LAG(state) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY currentdate) AS yesterday_state
```

Now I want to count how long the state has been the same value and im doing so with this:

```
COUNT (CASE WHEN state = yesterday_state THEN state ELSE NULL END) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY currentdate AS state_age
```

This is working properly but I need to find a way to set the value back to 0 when state != yesterday_state

This all is happening inside of SELECT statement as I'm creating a view. How could I go around doing this so that the state_age sets to 0 when state is not the same value as yesterday_state

SOLUTION:

```
CREATE VIEW view AS (
    WITH
        cte1 AS (SELECT *, LAG(state) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY currentdate) AS state_yesterday
            FROM table),
        cte2 AS (SELECT *, CASE WHEN state = state_yesterday THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS state_remained
            FROM cte1),
        cte3 AS (SELECT *, CASE WHEN state_remained != 0 THEN SUM(state_remained) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id, state ORDER BY currentdate) ELSE 0 END AS state_age_days
            FROM cte2)
        SELECT *
        FROM cte3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Schematically

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, LAG(state) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS prev_state 
          FROM sourcetable),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, CASE WHEN state = prev_state THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS state_changed 
          FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT *, SUM(state_changed) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) AS group_number 
          FROM cte2 )
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY group_number) AS group_count 
FROM cte3
```

For multiple entities add proper partitioning / partitioning level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think there is still something im missing. The group number and group count just keep static over the rows. I use the following code: `WITH
        cte1 AS (SELECT *, LAG(state) OVER(ORDER BY currentdate) AS state_yesterday
            FROM table),
        cte2 AS (SELECT *, CASE WHEN state = state_yesterday THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS state_changed
   FROM cte1),
   cte3 AS (SELECT *, SUM(state_changed) OVER(ORDER BY currentdate) AS group_number
 FROM cte2)
 SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY group_number) AS group_count
 FROM cte3 `

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "groups" where state has not changed like:

```
SELECT t.* 
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id
                          ORDER BY currentdate)
     - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, state
                          ORDER BY currentdate) as grp
FROM table t
```

You can then apply whatever aggregate you want to on this group. Example:

```
SELECT MIN(currentdate) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, grp) as FIRST_DATE
     , MAX(currentdate) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, grp) as LAST_DATE
     , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, grp) as #SIZE
     , t.itemid, t.state
FROM ( 
    SELECT t.* 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id
                           ORDER BY currentdate)
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, state
                           ORDER BY currentdate) as grp
    FROM table t
);
```